# Basic Logic operators both AND and OR

Tags: logic, operands

Hi I have tree conditions

A, B and C

Now, I want to apply these conditions I such a way, that if any of these conditions is true, or a combination, the whole outcome is true.

If I do

A || B || C

then as soon as A is true, B and C are not evaluated

if I do

A && B && C

it's only true if ALL of them are true.

Is there a special notation for fulfilling my wishes?

Comment: In the second case, for A && B && C, if A is false, then B and C are not evaluated. Note that this is assumes [short circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the Or (||) operator will give you the correct answer because it does not need to evaluate the other conditions but if you want B and C to be evaluated even if A is True then you should nest the If statements such as:

```
if A == True
    do something;
    if B == True
        do something;
        if C == True
            do something;
```

Or just do three separate If statements.

Answer (score 0):

You have answered your own question.

You want a situation whereby if EITHER `A` OR `B` OR `C` is true, or if a combination such as `A` AND `B` are true then the whole expression will evaluate to true.

That is `A || B || C`. If you only care about requiring ANY of the conditions to be true, then there is no need to evaluate all the conditions because as long as ONE condition is true, then your whole expression or outcome is true.

If you care about the specific combinations being true TOGETHER then you can group them using parenthesis as such:

If I want `A` AND `B` to be true at the same time OR `C`: `(A && B) || C`
If I want `A` AND `C` to be true at the same time OR `B`: `(A && C) || B`